# Accept Nested Attribures For '_attributes' Suffix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I'm doing an API and I'm using the Has_many association, and since I wanna to create a model when I create his father, I decided to use accepts_nested_attributes for.
And based on my knowledge, if I don use the "_attributes" suffix it raises me a error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

In the API I do this for a Post requisition:

```
{
    "content": {
        "name": "Teste",
        "schedulings_attributes":[
            {
                "days_attributes": [
                        {
                            "start": "2011-10-28",
                            "end": "2010-09-07"
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "2012-08-30",
                            "end": "2017-06-31"
                        }
                    ],
                    "hours_attributes": [
                        {
                            "start": "2000-01-01T01:51:30.000Z",
                            "end": "2000-01-01T15:03:11.000Z"
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "2000-01-01T02:23:39.000Z",
                            "end": "2000-01-01T00:37:51.000Z"
                        }
                    ],
                    "week_attributes": {
                        "monday": true,
                        "thursday": true,
                        "wednesday": true,
                        "tuesday": true,
                        "friday": true,
                        "saturday": true,
                        "sunday": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The thing is, I don't wanna the '_attributes' suffix.
There is a way to take it of without raising an error in the active record? With some treatment at the controller?

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered a way to do this with a treatment.

```
def scheduling_treatment(treated_params)
   treated_params[:schedulings].map do |attributes|
      attributes[:days_attributes] = attributes.delete(:days)
      attributes[:hours_attributes] = attributes.delete(:hours)
      attributes[:week_attributes] = attributes.delete(:week)
   end
   treated_params
end
```

In the method above, I receive the key schedulings, and mapping it I grab the keys and delete the old key and exchanges it for the new with the suffix '_attributes'.
Inside the controller:

```
def content_params
   new_params = params.require(:content).permit(:id, :name, schedulings: [
        days: [:start, :end],
        hours: [:start, :end],
        week: [:monday, :thursday, :wednesday, :tuesday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday]])
        new_params = scheduling_treatment(new_params)
        new_params[:schedulings_attributes] = new_params.delete(:schedulings)
        new_params.permit!
end
```